# Accessing a variable from a method deep within a class

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I access the variable `name` in the `foreach` loop and under the `try` below? I need to reference it in my Main class. Sorry of this is a dumb question.

```
 public class DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {

    public DragDropRichTextBox()
    {
        //Enables drag and drop on this class.
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragDrop += DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop;
    }

    public void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {        

        string[] _fileText;
        _fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];


        if (_fileText != null)
        {
            foreach (string name in _fileText)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString(name));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is where I need to call it from my Main class (See "HERE" below):

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, HERE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear how your first class and your main class relate to each other.  You have `name` in a loop in which you could have multiple values, so are you asking for all the values, the first value, the last value?  More information is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain and simple, you **absolutely cannot**.

That variable is scoped to that `foreach` loop. There is no way to access it outside of the loop, because it *doesn't even exist* outside of the loop.

Without the loop, it would be scoped to the `try` block, and without that, the method. Even in those situations, the *variable does not exist outside its scope*.

And even if it did, what value would it hold? Its an iteration variable, so it changes on each pass of the loop. The whole thing just wouldn't make sense.

If you need to access data it pointed to/held, then you need to store it off in a *class-level* variable, or in this case, put each value into an `IEnumerable<String>`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `the DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop._fileText` and then just recreate the `foreach` loop? I'm not sure how to access the `_fileText` variable from another class either since it's based on an event (i.e. DragDrop).

Comment: I'm sorry, let me try what you've already suggested first. I appreciated the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Getting into some weird stuff here, but I'll just answer your question and leave it at that. Just a heads up, the (name) you're referring to will constantly change values as you move through your foreach loop.

```
public class DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static List<string> NameList; // Create instance variable

    public DragDropRichTextBox()
    {
        //Enables drag and drop on this class.
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragDrop += DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop;
    }

    public void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] _fileText;
            _fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];


            if (_fileText != null)
            {
                foreach (string name in _fileText)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString(name);
                        NameList.Add(name); // Assign it inside loop
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {                        
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, DragDropRichTextBox.Name);
            }
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer his question??? And variable scoping isn't all that weird, and *very* important to understand.

Comment: He asked for the 'name' and this gives it to him. I never said scoping was weird (and I agree its important to understand), his question and coding style is weird. Regardless, I answered the questioned he asked while also mentioning that the 'name' he's referring to will change as it iterates through the foreach loop.

Comment: You just said "getting into some weird stuff" which confused me. Consider highlighting your change, as it wasn't apparent just glancing through the code. (wasn't the DV btw)

Comment: Sorry, when I said 'weird stuff' I was referring to his question, what he was trying to achieve, and the way he was going about it. I didn't want to dive too deep into how it should be setup so I just answered his question, left a comment about an issue (that we all saw) and let it go.